# Match specific url patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have the following pattern check:

```
const myPattern = /^\/(abc|def|gh|how-to\/articles|xyz){1}/I;
```

The above matches something like `www.test.com/how-to/articles` & `www.test.com/how-to/articles/<anything>`

How to tweak my pattern above so that it matches

`www.test.com/how-to/articles/<anything>` and not `www.test.com/how-to/articles`

Tried the following with no luck:

```
const myPattern = /^\/(abc|def|gh|how-to\/articles\/.*|xyz){1}/I;

const myPattern = /^\/(abc|def|gh|how-to\/articles\/.|xyz){1}/I;
```

Comment: Try `/^\/(?:abc|def|gh|how-to\/articles\/.+|xyz)/i`